# how to protect specific type of files in mvc to access by any user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

if i want to protect to access any xml file from our site in mvc then how can i write the code. can i do it with the help of http handler. if yes just give some sample code which can run in mvc. if is there any other better mvc specific technique exist then please share those idea with me. i want that when user try to access xml file from my site like typing file path www.mysite.com/myfolder/test.xml then i will show a message to user that these kind of file is not accessible. how to do it....guide me.

few guys told me to put the files in data folder and few said to look at BlockViewHandler.

at the moment i have no idea about BlockViewHandler  in mvc but i would definitely look at it. my requirement is something like when any user try to access any xml file whereever it is stored in my site and also i want to check which xml file and from which folder the xml exist? if my condition meet then i want to redirect user to specific view with specific message like "Access denied for the blah blah" etc. can i do it with the help of BlockViewHandler ?

please discuss all other possible ways to accomplish this task. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try HttpModules or global Action Filters.

Check this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Basically global filters will handle each request. They provide some place for you to process requests and send approppriate response (if necessary).

You should write ordinary ASP.NET MVC Action Filter and then register it globally in Global.asax.

Comment: how can i do it with global Action. basically i want to write very minimum code in common base area for that and reuse from anywhere.can u plzz redirect me to right article for protecting files with global Action. thanks